# safely delete all old git commits on both local and remote bare repository?

Tags: git

I am a beginner in topics related to the git "language", that is not always of immediate understanding for me (merge, "fast forward", ticket-tracking system, etc... sounds cryptic).

NOW MY PROBLEM:

- i have a bare repository on one machine
- a local repository on the same machine
- a local repository on my laptop (here remote configured via ssh).
- there is only one branch (master) on all repositories.

when I finish coding on one machine I commit and push on the bare repository. Then on the other machine I pull from the bare repository. And this every time I switch, so no conflicts originates.

**Now both the bare repository and the local repository (on the same machine where the bare repository is; not on the laptop) are "too big" and I need to free old commits.**

```
  What is the simplest and safest way to do this ?
```

In addition if I want to remove a directory form a set of consecutive commits in both the repositories (local and remote bare) how can this be safely and easily done ?

The git book didn't make me feel comfortable. THX

Comment: If you are talking about a "too big" repository what do you mean with that? What kind of data do you track?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you may try is to pack repository using `git gc --prune --aggressive`. Before issuing this operation make sure that you don't need any recent "abandoned commits". This operation cleans "garbage" from your repository (temporary commits, commits existed before rebases etc) and thus the output of `git reflog` is clean after garbage collecting.

If the size of .git/ is still too big for you, you may consider simplify your history (e.g. by merging a lot of small changes into one big change), or simply cutting off older commits. But this actually should be discussed with your collegues and other involved persons. Usually it's not required even for really big projects with a lot of changes and a big codebase.

Also you may consider to use incomplete history on your notebook (using `git clone --depth ....`, see man page) but remember that you can't make new commits in a such "partial" repository, only create patches and apply them on a complete repo.